# What is being done to improve new question quality?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, quality-filter

## TL;DR

What exactly has been tried in the past to address new question quality, what is currently being done, and how are the current tactics being assessed?

### Intro

This post is to highlight my experience as a user who:

- cares about improving the content posted and maintained on Stack Overflow
- likes helping others and interested in increasing personal reputation on the network

### Observations over the past 18 months of participation:

- **zero** improvement in the question quality
- users who contribute their **time** to assist in tedious moderation tasks such
  as "REVIEW QUEUES" and flagging posts get little to no value from these activities
- increasing trend for "troubleshooting" questions
- new users continuing to post the same low-quality questions which are often not relevant or off-topic for SO
- **earning reputation has turned into a grind, given the lack of legitimate questions**

  - "low-hanging fruit" usually are duplicates or have some other defect, often resulting in deletion (which is good for the community but creates a problem for the user who spends time answering a now-deleted question).
- wasted energy and useless, distracting behavior from moderator and Stack Overflow management politics

Comment: The ask question page got an update. And SE tries to get new users into The Loop.

Comment: @rene Why do they do that?

Comment: @akuzminykh I guess because they think it is better to ask those new users directly instead of relying on a bunch of grumpy, well-seasoned and articulate Meta regulars ...

Comment: Nothing substantial can be done because 'bums on sites' is the prevailing metric for accountants and shareholders.  Since homework vamps make up the largest portion of new accounts, (those who get the most adverts), the quality battle is over, and has been for some time:(

Comment: @MartinJames Would it be different if SO was financed by crowdfunding?

Comment: "crowdfunding" If you're interested in that idea, go check out Codidact.com (although they don't have any immediate plans for a programming site).

Comment: The obvious alternative to only showing ads to new users, and therefore relying on them for revenue, is perhaps to show ads to other users as well and not switching the entire model to crowdfunding?

Comment: "zero improvement in the question quality" To be fair, the average question quality is also determined by the question creators a lot. It's not like we other users or the company have complete control over the process. It could also just be that folks nowadays don't ask that good questions anymore. I think you have a good description of the problems, it may be worth to think a bit more about the underlying reasons but coming up with solutions won't be easy at all. Question quality is the heart of all problems of SO currently (I would say).

Comment: @Trilarion you make a very valid point and I appreciate the perspective your comment provided me.

Comment: @Trilarion True enough. SO can't do anything about the quality of questions that people want to ask. The name of the game is blocking content which is against the rules so you at least have to wade through less content which needs moderation, but even if the site would do that perfectly...It's like those gold digging programs on Discovery; they dig and sift for tiny nuggets, not giant veins. You can't just pick up a rock off the floor and say "look, I'm rich!". Similarly, you can't just open the SO front page and pick a random question expecting it to be everything you hoped for.

Comment: @Gimby Good analogy. SO could maybe ask people with questions but without sufficient rep to show that they know how to ask a good question for money in order to pay for the curation work of their content, but it might just not be economically viable. Doing mostly thankless curation work for free might also not work in the long run. Probably leaves us with developing an AI that can do curation (and then one that can do the answering and we are done).

Comment: @Gimby I sometimes think when looking at the main page that I can predict if a question gets closed or ends up with a negative score with quite some accuracy even from the question title alone. But then I have lots of experience with good and bad questions. Not sure how well ML would do currently for that.

Comment: _"earning reputation has turned into a grind, given the lack of legitimate questions"_ - I've been on SO for 10 years and it has always been the case. I doubt grinding reputation on new (and bad) questions is a trend that started during the last 18 months. Also, the Legendary badge encourages that grind and this badge always existed.

Comment: @Trilarion _"It could also just be that folks nowadays don't ask that good questions anymore."_ It could also just be that most good questions have already been asked. Everything about JavaScript, Python, C#, Java, PHP and so on is already answered on SO. Furthermore, there is a trend coming from new/niche technology communities to not use SO to handle questions. I got this info from the people working on Nim, they disagree with SO policies and elitism, and recommend their users to ask questions on their forum. Which is sad because new/niche technologies bring good questions.

Comment: @GG Yes, that could also be. I personally have not heard from many people not recommending SO. People working on Nim disagreeing with SO policies and elitism sounds kind of catchy but I wonder what they really mean by that? At least there does not seem to be a [Nim tag on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nim). SO still seems to be the juggernaut in terms of amount of questions though.

Comment: @Trilarion This is the one: [`nim-lang`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nim-lang). The latest question was 19 days ago. _"People working on Nim disagreeing with SO policies and elitism sounds kind of catchy but I wonder what they really mean by that?"_ They mean the same thing that you can read over and over on Reddit, Hacker News, etc… when SO is brought up in a discussion. They think SO is not welcoming. They don't understand why their questions are closed and tagged "low quality", "irrelevant" or "duplicate". Not taking a side here, just describing what I often read about SO.

Comment: @GG That tag search on SO is terrible. I searched for "nim". Thanks for the explanation. This is kind of the usual stuff.

Comment: I cannot answer the question, since I don't have insight into what the company does, but I get the feeling that rather than discouraging bad questions, Stackoverflow it trying to attract quantity rather than quality.